# Firefox table absolute positioning: bug or feature?

Tags: css, firefox, gecko

I am absolute positioning an element inside a `position: relative` table cell with a thick border and using `box-sizing: border-box`. I expect the position to be relative to the **inside** of the cell's border (which is the case in Chrome and Safari), but in Firefox the position is relative to the **centre** of the border. (Note that this only affects the table cells and not the following div.)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yz1jnh65/5/)

My question is: which positioning behaviour is correct? Secondarily, have bug reports been filed to the respective project(s)?

Comment: Probably related to how Firefox handles collapsing borders. Firefox behaves as expected when using separated borders. The answer to your question is probably ["none of the above."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206085/is-the-collapsing-border-models-implementation-in-web-browsers-valid)