# MS Edge CSS border rendering order

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-tables

I've got a little problem with Microsoft Edge:

It is about the rendering priority of borders of a table when `border-collapse: collapse;` is set.
I've read about those priorities that there are rules, which borders are rendered with higher priorites:
From less important to more important: table, tbody, tr, td... also the border styles itself: double over single and so on.

The normal behaviour for a table with collapsed borders and inner borders with a different color is, that the inner borders 'bleed' into the outer ones: https://jsfiddle.net/fpyf1kL7/3/ (this is true for Chrome, FF and Edge).

So to not let the inner borders 'bleed' into the outer ones I found a quickfix by setting the border style of the table itself to 'double' while still having it at 1px width (thus it appears as 'solid): https://jsfiddle.net/fpyf1kL7/4/ , but that only works in Chrome and FF. In Microsoft Edge, the inner borders still 'bleeds' into the outer one.

I've already found a workaround for that issue by using `border-collapse: separate;` and `border-spacing: 0;`: https://jsfiddle.net/fpyf1kL7/2/ . This works in Chrome, FF and Edge. But now the borders are not collapsed anymore, so I am not able to have a border on tbody or tr elements anymore and I have to be cautionous not to have adjacent borders.

So real questions here are:

1. Why is Microsoft Edge handling the collapsed border rendering issue differently?
2. Is there a way to get it working correctly (not 'bleeding') in Microsoft Edge with collapsed borders?

Comment: Why? Because no one is interested in even trying to make collapsed borders look consistent across browsers. See also [Is the collapsing border model's implementation in web browsers valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206085/is-the-collapsing-border-models-implementation-in-web-browsers-valid)

Comment: So neither the implementations are consistent across browsers (that was obvious), nor the specification is sufficient in some cases (as stated from the CSS Working Group itself). It seems that there is little hope that this issue will be consistent anytime.